# ApplicationInsights in React

Tags: reactjs, azure-application-insights

I'm fairly new to application insights and I'm trying to get it running on my react app in that sense, that there's a wrapper-component initiating the configuration / connection to the application-insights service.

When i instantiate the Wrapper-Component and nest another component, which should have access to the appInsights-object (making trackEvent, -trace, -error methods available), in it, the child Component states, that appInsights is not defined.

So in essence the component structure, simplified, looks something like this:

```
<WrapperService> // initializes appInsights
  <ChildComponent> // should have access to the appInsights-Object in Order to fire Events
</WrapperService>
```

To be specific about the goal at hand: How can i pass down the appInsights object to be able to use it in any component i want?

Any other suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tring to add application insights into child components you can use the React Hooks.

Follow the steps to achieve this:

Adding application insights in react refer [here](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-10-04-implementing-monitoring-in-react-using-appinsights/)

Once added the application insights in your react app Try to create the context file like `AppInsightsContext.js`

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { reactPlugin } from "./AppInsights";
const AppInsightsContext = createContext(reactPlugin);
const AppInsightsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    return (
        <AppInsightsContext.Provider value={reactPlugin}>
        {children}
    </AppInsightsContext.Provider>
    );
};
export { AppInsightsContext, AppInsightsContextProvider };
```

Now, we have a component that sets up the reactPlugin. We need to add it in our react application.

In the **Layout/index.js** file we need set the context up as high.

```
const LayoutWithContext = ({ location, children }) => (
< AppInsightsContextProvider>
    <>
    <Headroom
        upTolerance={10}
        downTolerance={10}
        style={{ zIndex: "20", height: "6.5em" }} >
        
        < Header location={location} />
    < /Headroom>
    < Container text>{children}</Container>
    < Footer />
    </>
< /AppInsightsContextProvider>
);
```

Context is now in use and all **children** components are able to access it within our children components.

If You wanted to use the **standard page** interaction tracking of the React plugin you can combine this with the **HOC**(Higher Order component)

```
import React from "react";
import Headroom from "react-headroom";
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Footer from "../Footer";
import Header from "../Header";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import { AppInsightsContextProvider } from "../../AppInsightsContext";
import withAppInsights from "../../AppInsights";

const Layout = withAppInsights(({ location, children }) => (
    <>
    <Headroom
    upTolerance={10}
    downTolerance={10}
    style={{ zIndex: "20", height: "6.5em" }} >
        <Header location={location} />
    </Headroom>
    <Container text>{children}</Container>
    <Footer />
    </>
));

const LayoutWithContext = ({ location, children }) => (
    <AppInsightsContextProvider>
        <Layout location={location} children={children} />
    </AppInsightsContextProvider>
);

export default LayoutWithContext;
```

**Exposing Context as a Hook**

The final thing we can do with our new Context-provided react Plugin is to make it easier to access it and to do that we’ll use the useContext Hook. To do this it’s a simple matter of updating `AppInsightsContext.js`:

```
const useAppInsightsContext = () => useContext(AppInsightsContext);
```

Creating a Hook for Tracking events Refer [here](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-11-19-combining-react-hooks-with-appinsights/#creating-a-hook-for-tracking-events)

Refer  [this article](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-11-19-combining-react-hooks-with-appinsights/) for more infomation